# Where can I find unfiltered search query statistics?

Tags: seo, analytics, search, statistics

I would like to learn more about upcoming trends and I also need it for seo. I know Google Trends, but it displays only filtered statistics about what and how people search.
Can you recommend me any alternatives?

( I know this question may not seem to fit perfectly into the pro webmasters section. But think of doing seo for adult and gaming sites. So I think it's a relevant question here. )

Comment: Did you try Adwords Keyword tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try Google Keyword Research Tool !! it will provide perfect insight about estimated search query and competition.